# Vectorized method of generating sequence from multiple start and end points in R

Tags: r

Does R have a vecorized method of generating sequences from multiple start and end points? I can only figure out how to do it using some form of loop as shown below (note: I could use apply but I'm hoping for a truly vectorized solution)

```
starts <- c(1,2,3)
ends <- c(10,11,12)
mySequences <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
for(i in 1:3){
  mySequences[i,] <- seq(starts[i], ends[i], length.out = 10)
}
```

but ideally I'd like it to be something that like the following:

```
mySequences <- seq(starts, ends, length.out = 10)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would `t(mapply(":", starts, ends))` be good enough?

Comment: Or `t(embed(1:12, 3)[, 3:1])`

Comment: Well in a fit of stupidity I created a toy example that's simpler than what I'm actually trying to do my list of starts and ends looks more like:

`starts <- c(486.3, 89.1, 38.4)
ends <- c(595.1, 103.8, 40)`

That being said Richard or WD11's answers might work but my linear algebra is too rusty to figure it out right now. With regards to Julius and Martin both would work but I'm trying for the fastest simplest solutions since the code is run in simulation many many times. If I can't find something better I'll go with mapply.

Comment: For fixed output length 10?

Comment: Yes output length is fixed, in my case its 100 but its fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how do you like this type of thing:

> `outer(X=c(1:3), Y=c(0:9), FUN="+")`

Answer (score 0):

If as in your example the widths are all the same (`starts = 1:3; ends = 10:8; wd=10`) then create a matrix where each row is the sequence `1:wd` using R's recycling rule to fill the matrix efficiently

```
m = matrix(seq(wd) - 1, length(starts), wd, byrow=TRUE)
```

scale the rows by the amount each column needs to be incremented, and add the starts, again using R's (column-wise) recycling

```
m * (ends - starts) / (wd - 1) + starts
```

As a function

```
seqs_wd = function(starts, ends, wd=10) {
    m = matrix(seq(wd) - 1, length(starts), wd, byrow=TRUE)
    m * (ends - starts) / (wd - 1) + starts
}
```

a simple example

```
> seqs_wd(1:3, 10:8)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]
[1,]    1 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 8.000000
[2,]    2 2.777778 3.555556 4.333333 5.111111 5.888889 6.666667 7.444444
[3,]    3 3.555556 4.111111 4.666667 5.222222 5.777778 6.333333 6.888889
         [,9] [,10]
[1,] 9.000000    10
[2,] 8.222222     9
[3,] 7.444444     8
```

and compared to the simple implementation

```
f0 = function(starts, ends, wd=10)
    mapply(seq, starts, ends, length.out=10)
```

some timings

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> n = 1000
> starts = runif(n, 100, 200); ends = starts + runif(n, 100, 200)
> microbenchmark(seqs_wd(starts, ends), f0(starts, ends))
Unit: microseconds
                  expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq
 seqs_wd(starts, ends)   203.075   210.0705   219.3789   218.3225   223.8625
      f0(starts, ends) 17037.229 17370.7835 18468.4581 17862.2775 18629.8510
       max neval
   326.677   100
 32766.215   100
```

or with `n = 1000000`

```
> microbenchmark(seqs_wd(starts, ends), f0(starts, ends), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max
 seqs_wd(starts, ends) 318.1302 321.2502 327.4233 322.2663 326.0085 370.875
 neval
    10
```

so about a third of a second for a million sequences.